# Send xml file in textarea form in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, curl

I need to send content of my xml file located on server to text form.
I try to use curl method in PHP, but i don't know how to read content from xml file and save it to variable. What's wrong?

Here **PHP-code:**

```
if ($model->getSOrderStatuses()->id == 1) {
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->openURI('uploads/files/orders.xml');
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->startElement("order"); //start root
$xml->writeElement("id", $model->getId());
$xml->writeElement("date", gmdate("Y-m-d\/H:i:s", $model->getDateCreated()));
$xml->writeElement("customer", $model->getUserFullName());
$xml->writeElement("phone", $model->getUserPhone());
$xml->writeElement("email", $model->getUserEmail());
$xml->writeElement("delivery_type", $model->getSDeliveryMethods()->getId());
$xml->writeElement("delivery_adress", $model->getUserDeliverTo());
$xml->writeElement("payment_type", $model->getSPaymentMethods()->getId());
$xml->writeElement("comment", $model->getUserComment());
$xml->startElement("products");  //open element
foreach ($model->getSOrderProductss() as $sOrderProduct) {
$total = $total + $sOrderProduct->getQuantity() * $sOrderProduct->toCurrency();
$product = $sOrderProduct->getSProducts();
$xml->startElement("row");       //open element
$xml->writeAttribute("code", $product->getUrl());
$xml->writeAttribute("qty", $sOrderProduct->getQuantity());
$xml->writeAttribute("price", $sOrderProduct->toCurrency());
$xml->writeAttribute("sum", $sOrderProduct->getQuantity() * $sOrderProduct-    >toCurrency());
$xml->endElement();  //close element
}
$xml->endElement();  //close element
$xml->writeElement("sum", my_money_format('',$total));
$xml->endElement();  //close root
$xml->flush();
$xmlorder = 'uploads/files/orders.xml';
$ch = curl_init('http://pathtomyserver/?action=newor');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlorder);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
echo($xmlorder);
$info=curl_getinfo($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
}
}
```

**form:**

>>link

Comment: When a form is submitted, there's no such thing as "text field", "textarea", "radio", "checkbox", etc... There's just key=value pairs. Since your textarea is named `xml`, you'd submit `xml=your_xml_data_goes_here`

Comment: for clarification: You want your php script to send an http request as if the (contents of the) xml document has been pasted to the textarea and the form submitted in a browser? Strangley enough the form tag is closed immediately - the text area is not a child of the form: `<form name="HansaForm" action="" method="POST"></form>`

Comment: oh and btw: no offense, just: `<x-sas-window top="60" ...` Claris Home Page? In 2014? Really? ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK no, it is not a home page, just special page of our ERP/CRM system for data exchange :)

Comment: Didn't say anything about a home page. Claris Home Page is/was a tool for editing html documents like FrontPage. `x-sas-window` is just one of its "footprints". see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claris_Home_Page

Comment: @VolkerK Oh, okay, thanks for the clarification. This software uses its own proprietary web server and utilities to generate forms and pages, and i have no idea how it works.

Comment: Quite frankly, neither do I. I don't see something that transmits any data anywhere. Just a form element without any submittable elements (let alone successful elements, i.e. those that really get transfered as key=value pairs). Just out of curiosity I've copy&pasted the html code and guess what: pressing the button did ...bupkis. This, _exactly_ this html document/form does something for you?

Comment: @VolkerK you try to submit some text, using this [link](http://p.novasports.com.ua:1080/?action=newor) and i want my script to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```
$xml = file_get_contents("path/to/xml.xml");
```

Then simply output to textarea

```
<textarea name="xml"><?php echo $xml; ?>
```

Comment: this form is located on another server

Comment: when outputing the content in the text area I get wrong characters like <�?xml version="1.0"?>. How to solve this?